# org-agenda files variable: I'm not sure that the value is set just on init.el

Tags: variables

Pressing  `C-h v` I can see the value of this variable.
In my `init.el` I've commented out this variable assignment: `;;(setq org-agenda-files '( "~/org/*.org"))`, and restarted Emacs.

But if I then try `C-h v`, it says the value still has all the folders that were included before).  Is this variable set in some other place? How can it be already be set if I've commented the code that does it?

Comment: The question, and what you're actually doing, are unclear. Please provide a recipe to reproduce the problem, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file).

Comment: These details belong in the *question*: please edit the question and add them. Comments are for *us* to ask clarification questions of you: *you* should answer such comments by editing the question which has to be complete on its own. Comments are not searchable and can be deleted.

Comment: If you don't set it during initialization (e.g. when you start with `emacs -Q`), `org-agenda-files` should be `nil`. If not, you might be doing something wrong, or your distro might be doing something wrong: it's hard to tell without more experiments and additional details.

Comment: ok, How can I definitely clear my org-agenda-file variable?

Comment: how can I definitely clear org-agenda-files?
this entry on init.el seem not working (setq org-agenda-files '( ""))

Comment: It is supposed to be `nil` if not set explicitly. So you have to find out who sets it and delete that setting. As I said `emacs -Q` should have it set to `nil`. And *please* update your question with the details - Comments are not for conversations.

Comment: 1. Are you using any Emacs distribution/starter kit? Then usually it helps to include that info in the question. 2. I guess you should use `(setq org-agenda-files nil)` (instead of `'( "")`)  3. As point 2 will also not help here, try to add `(debug-on-variable-change 'org-agenda-files)` to your init file and restart Emacs, to help find out where it gets set. 4. Please, instead of replying with a comment, update your question. Thanks!